# Wrap paired span to a new span

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

**CONTENTEDITABLE DIV** sample string only

```
int main(){

 if((x<3 && x!=5) || x>10)
   //execute statement;

 while((y<10) && (y>1))
   //execute statement;

}
```

**EXISTING HTML OF THE DIV**

```
<div id="board_code">
 <div>int main<span class="openParen bm1">(</span><span class="closeParen bm1">)</span></div>
 <div></div>
 <div>if<span class="openParen bm2">(</span><span class="openParen bm3">(</span>x<3 && x!=5<span class="closeParen bm3">)</span> || x>10<span class="closeParen bm2">)</span></div>
 <div>//execute statement;</div>
 <div>while<span class="openParen bm4">(</span><span class="openParen bm5">(</span>y<10<span class="closeParen bm5">)</span> && <span class="openParen bm6">(</span>y>1<span class="closeParen bm6">)</span><span class="closeParen bm4">)</span></div>
 <div>//execute statement;</div>
 <div>}</div>
</div>
```

**TARGET HTML**

```
<div id="board_code">
 <div>int main<span class="parenWrap"><span class="openParen bm1">(</span><span class="closeParen bm1">)</span></span></div>
 <div></div>
 <div>if<span class="parenWrap"><span class="openParen bm2">(</span><span class="parenWrap"><span class="openParen bm3">(</span>x<3 && x!=5<span class="closeParen bm3">)</span></span> || x>10<span class="closeParen bm2">)</span></span></div>
 <div>//execute statement;</div>
 <div>while<span class="parenWrap"><span class="openParen bm4">(</span><span class="parenWrap"><span class="openParen bm5">(</span>y<10<span class="closeParen bm5">)</span></span> && <span class="parenWrap"><span class="openParen bm6">(</span>y>1<span class="closeParen bm6">)</span></span><span class="closeParen bm4">)</span></span></div>
 <div>//execute statement;</div>
 <div>}</div>
</div>
```

I've already matched the `()` by having a pair of `bm1, bm2`, etc.. Now, i need to wrap the `openParen bm(n)` to `closeParen bm(n)` with `span class = parenWrap`. See, I have already determined the paren pairs, Now i need to wrap them as a whole so that i can evaluate them later, its close to HIGHLIGHTING, but i wont really highlight it, i will evaluate the text between the pairs.

How can i achieve this?

I tried this but its not working

```
$('.openParen, .bm0').first().nextUntil('.closeParen, .bm0').last().wrapAll('<span class="parenWrap"></span>');
//this must loop to all the bm's by the way
```

Comment: This question is very poorly edited. You need to add more words to describe your problem. Currently it looks like a big pile of code.

Comment: @MarsOne: hmm? look at the simplified block, OP wanted to wrap the first openParen bm0 to its paired closeParen bm0